# Python - Capitalize the first letter of the each word except the word and

Tags: python, python-2.7

In order to capitalize the first letter of each word I know we can use the following method

```
category = "foo and bar"
category.title()
```

What if I only want the `foo` and `bar` to get their first letter calitalized but not the word `and`

The end result I am looking for is

`Foo and Bar`

Any tips on how to achieve this? I am using Python 2.7

Comment: search and replace `And` with `and` after using `title` .... `category.title().replace('And', 'and')`

Comment: won't work with `Andy`

Comment: use regex `re.sub(r'\bAnd\b', 'and', 'Foo And Bar')` then, or use space (if it is always the case) `category.title().replace(' And ', ' and ')`

Comment: I'd do `" ".join([x if x=="and" else x.title() for x in category.split()])`

Comment: ok, no room for answers with all those comments :) closing,

Comment: thank you all for the feedbacks